# redips - REDIPS.drag.enableDrag('init') gives error "'Cannot read property 'nestedGroup' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, drag, redips.drag

when I try to reinitialize my redips div elements in my table I do this:

```
REDIPS.drag.enableDrag('init');
```

Redips fails on the following source code:

```
tableTop = function (obj) {
    var e,      // element
        i,      // loop variable
        tmp,    // temporary storage (needed for exchanging array members)
        group;  // tables group
    // find table for clicked DIV element
    e = findParent('TABLE', obj);
    // set tables group
    group = e.redips.nestedGroup;
    ...
```

With the following error:

> Cannot read property 'nestedGroup' of undefined

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initiated redips before my table was created dynamically.
You have to call REDIPS.drag.init(); after the table was created.